# Problem trying to @Override the addViewControllers() method - Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm following this tutorial [Part 5: Integrating Spring Security with Spring Boot Web](https://justinrodenbostel.com/2014/05/30/part-5-integrating-spring-security-with-spring-boot-web/) trying to add the Spring Security functionality to my web page but I'm having heaps of config problems.

So I've got to this part where I need to `@Override` this method:

```
@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
}
```

But I'm not quite sure where to put the code. I've googled and found that most people put it in the class that extends the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` but this is not working in my case, I'm getting an error saying that the method doesn't override any method from its superclass.

This is my `SecurityConfig` that extends the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().permitAll();

        http
            .formLogin().failureUrl("/ingresar?error")
                        .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
            .loginPage("/ingresar").permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                     .logoutSuccessUrl("/logout")
                     .permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
    }
}
```

Any idea ?? I've been trying for hours !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This mapping has nothing common with the security itself. It is just a controller definition to return a view.

You surely have a class implementing [`WebMvcConfigurer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurer.html) and annotated with  [`@Configuration`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html) annotation. If not, create it. Include this method override up there.

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

   @Override
   public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
       registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
   }
}
```

Note the class has a lot of default methods available to be overridden. The method [`WebMvcConfigurer::addViewControllers`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurer.html#addViewControllers-org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry-) in surely there.

Comment: Thanks ... I don't have any class implementing the WebMvcConfigurer ... do you know any good tutorial for doing this ?? I'm going crazy man ... can't find something usefull out there

Comment: If you don't have this class, just create it. Take a look on the [Baledung's webpage - Securing a Web Application](https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/) and work with the official Spring documentation.

Answer (score 3):

You should have a `@Configuration` class that implements `WebMvcConfigurer`. There you can overrides `addViewControllers`

This will helps you:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks ... I don't have any class implementing the WebMvcConfigurer ... do you know any good tutorial for doing this ?? I'm going crazy man ... can't find something usefull out there

Comment: @NachoZveDeLaTorre just create that. create a class that has a `@Configuration` then implements `WebMvcConfigurer`. Spring will automatically config for you